# How to coalesce when all records are missing a column?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm reading multiple `JSON` files into a dataframe in Scala. A few files are missing a column (e.g. the column `header`) while other files have it. 
I want to add the column for those records where it doesn't exist and populate with a default value `"Missing"`. How to do it without impacting the records which already have the column?

I tried the below code, however, it only works if atleast one record has the column. If none of the records have the column, it errors out saying column `Seq_num` not found:

```
df.withColumn("Seq_num", coalesce(col("Seq_num"),lit("0")))
```

> Error: cannot resolve '`Seq_num`' given input columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function that first check if the column exists in the dataframe. If the column does not exist, simply add it. In the case it already exists then use `coalesce` as before.

This can be done as follows:

```
def coalesceColumn(df: DataFrame, column: String, default: String) = {
  Try(df(column)).toOption match {
    case Some(_) => df.withColumn(column, coalesce(col(column), lit(default)))
    case _ => df.withColumn(column, lit(default))
  }
}

val df2 = coalesceColumn(df, "Seq_num", "0")
```

Note that it's possible to use `df.columns.contains(column)` to do the column check but in that case nested columns are not supported.